Who all get notified when any comment is posted on an answer?
Alice asks a question. I reply to it. Alice comments on my answer. I automatically get notified because it's my answer.
Instead let's say I ask a question & Alice replies to it. I comment on Alice's answer. And then when Alice replies to my comment on her answer to my question, does she need to tag me? Or will I get automatically notified because I am the original questioner?
I remember that much earlier, this didn't happen automatically.
i.e. earlier the questioner got notified automatically only on comments on the question itself but not on answers.
But recently, I think this has changed. Just wanted to confirm if it's true because I still continue to explicitly tag when I reply to the questioner's comments on my answer. If it's confirmed I will stop doing it.
When I comment on someone else's question, the page doesn't allow me to tag the questioner. But I am still allowed to tag the questioner in comments on answers. Hence my confusion.
UPDATE:
I recently got a notification from a comment where I wasn't tagged - screenshot of the comment, it doesn't contain a tag to me & it's a comment on someone else's answer to my question.

This was the comment (if you see the comment, the person didn't explicitly tag me in the comment)
It was a comment on this answer - https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/104020/3941
I was the questioner for this answer.
And this is the screenshot of the tag I got - 
Hence my question

This question has been answered on meta as this is not site specific. If changes are made to the way that comments are handled then it will almost certainly be network wide, and any answer here may be out of date.

@MaartenBodewes - should I repost my question at the main meta site? Or can you migrate it?

No, because you've been served two links that already answer the question, and one of those links got closed because it was already answered elsewhere. For these kind of questions, please think if it could be network wide, and then search on Meta. Most likely they have already been answered. You can of course ask questions there if they are not, or ask in chat.

@MaartenBodewes - I have added screenshots of my tag to the question now which shows I got a tag. So that answer may be out of date

Alright, then it is time to make sure that the relevant answer gets updated. You could comment below on it. If you don't get an answer there then let me know and I'll ask in the Teachers Lounge (a wasp nest of moderators ;) ). Actually, that's what you should do in the future, I'll ask right now as I think the answers are less helpful than they should be.

Alright, it is in the mill :)

@MaartenBodewes - thank you very much. It doesn't happen all the time - only occasionally. I am unable to figure out what exactly differs when it happens.

The person posting the question does not get a notification from someone writing a comment under one of the answers. If you want to be notified of that, you have to add the question to your bookmarks. If you want OP to be notified when you write a comment to an answer, you have to ping them.
For more information, see How do comment @replies work?, which says:

if a user comments on their own post and there is only one other person who has previously commented on that post, then that person is also notified, even if @name is not used.

post here includes both questions & answers.

The person posting the question does not get a notification from someone writing a comment under one of the answers. - what if the questioner commented on the answer & the answerer was posting a comment after the questioner's comment. Does that still hold?

I have updated the question with a screenshot where I (as a questioner) got tagged on a comment on the answer.

I'll add another link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125208/when-exactly-do-i-get-comment-notifications .

@MaartenBodewes  - I got the reply in the other meta. As per the FAQ questions, if you are the only commenter on a "post", then you will get tagged if someone else comments. And "post" includes both "questions & answers". On that page, there wasn't a single other commenter on the question itself. And on the answer, I was the only commenter, hence when the answered comment in reply to my comment, I got a notification.

The answer in crypto meta says this but I assumed "post" means questions. If you include post to mean questions & answers, then it makes sense
